# Predicting Energy Consumption of different buildings

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning

I have the dataset which you can find the (updated) file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bn5z444ydc1i82h/new_kwh.xlsx?dl=0) , containing many different characteristics of different office buildings, including their surface area and number of people working in there. In total there are about 200 records. I want to use an algorithm, that can be trained using the dataset above, in order to be able to predict the electricity consumption(given in the column 'kwh') of a the building that is not in the set.

I have tried most of the possible machine learning algorithms using the scikit library in python (linear regression, Ridge, Lasso, SVC etc) in order to predict a continuous variable. Surface_area and number of workers had a coorelation value with the target variable between 0.3-0.4 so I assumed them to be good features for the model and included them in the training of the model. However I had about 13350 mean absolute error and R-squared value of about 0.22-0.35, which is not good at all.

I would be very grateful, if someone could give me some advice, or if you could examine a little the dataset and run some algorithms on it. What type of preprocessing should I use, and what type of algorithm? Is the number of datasets too low to train a regression model for predicting continuous variables?

Any feedback would be helpful as I am new to machine learning :)

Comment: Which correlation did you use ? I do not get values above 0.5 when using Pearson's .

Comment: Hey. Sorry. I was running it in a similar file. But now I checked it again, I am getting it between 0.3 - 0.4. I will make the edit in the description

Comment: Is this your entire dataset ? If so, it seems to small to draw conclusions

Comment: @GauthierFeuillen Yes. This is the only datasets we have. Is it possible to make a prediction algorithm with this much amount?

Comment: @greybeard Please try now.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that should be done in these kinds of Machine Learning Problems is to understand the data. Yes, the number of features in your dataset is small, yes, the number of data samples are very less, but it is important to do the best we can with what we have.

The data set header is in a language other than English, it is important to convert it to a language most of the people in the community would understand (in this case English). After doing a bit of tinkering, I found out that the language being used is Dutch.

There are some key features missing in the dataset. From something as obvious as the number of floors in the building to something not obvious like the number of working hours. Surface Area and the number of workers seems to me are the most important features, but you are missing out on a feature called building_function which (after using Google Translate) tells what the purpose of the building is. Intuitively, this is supposed to have a large correlation with the power consumption. Industries tend to use more power than normal Households. After translation, I found out that the main types were Residential, Office, Accommodation and Meeting. This feature thus has to be encoded as a nominal variable to train the model.

Another feature hoofsbi also seems to have some variance. But I do not know what that feature means.

If you could translate the headers in the data and share it, I will be able to provide you some code to perform this regression task. It is very important in such tasks to understand what the data is and thus perform feature engineering.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the response. Sorry about the dutch and I have updated it with a new file with the translations of the headers.
As for the hoofsbi, it is a standard code to classify corporations based on their economic and finance activiities in the Netherlands.

Comment: You can find the files here. [updated_file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bn5z444ydc1i82h/new_kwh.xlsx?dl=0)